# Crossdomain.xml for HTML 5 app

Tags: html, crossdomain.xml

I have an HTML5 app that will be a loading content (photos) from other sever. Before it was a flash app so simply crossdomain.xml would take care of that. Now, can I use the same crossdomain.xml file in the root?

here's the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="localhost" secure="false" />
<allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false" />
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

I'm trying and still getting error loading. Is there maybe any special method to implement that? I have access to both servers, the one with the HTML app and the other with the photos.

Answer (score 1):

The `crossdomain.xml` file only works within Flash applications as you stated. You probably want to take a look into cross-origin resource sharing (or CORS) which adds some simple HTTP headers that can whitelist cross domain requests.

On the server you're requesting to, you'll probably want to add a HTTP header like:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.example.com
```

replacing `example.com` with the domain you're requesting from. You can read more over on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).